# Polymorphic data transformation techniques / data lake/ big data

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, databricks, data-processing, data-preprocessing

Background: We are working on a solution to ingest huge sets of telemetry data from various clients. The data is in xml format and contains multiple independent groups of information which have a lot of nested elements. Clients have different versions and as a result the data is ingested in different but similar schema in the data lake. For instance a startDate field can be string or an object containing date. ) Our goal is to visualise accumulated  information in a BI tool.

Questions:
What are the best practices for dealing with polymorphic data?

- Process and transform required piece of data (reduced version) to a uni-schema file using a programming language and then process it in spark and databricks and consume in a  BI tool.
- Decompose data to the meaningful groups and process and join (using data relationships) them with spark and  databricks.

I appreciate your comments and sharing  opinions and experiences on this topic especially from subject matter experts and data engineers.  That would be siper nice if you could also share some useful resources about this particular topic.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the tags that you have selected for this thread is pointing out that you would like to use Databricks for this transformation. Databricks is one of the tools that I am using and think is powerful enough and effective to do this kind of data processing. Since, the data processing platforms that I have been using the most are Azure and Cloudera, my answer will rely on Azure stack because it is integrated with Databricks. here is what I would recommend based on my experience.

The first think you have to do is to define data layers and create a platform for them. Particularly, for your case, it should have Landing Zone, Staging, ODS, and Data Warehouse layers.

#### Landing Zone

Will be used for polymorphic data ingestion from your clients. This can be done by only [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/#overview) (ADF) connecting between the client and [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview). I recommend ,in this layer, we don't put any transformation into ADF pipeline so that we can create a common one for ingesting raw files. If you have many clients that can send data into Azure Storage, this is fine.  You can create some dedicated folders for them as well.

Normally, I create folders aligning with client types. For example, if I have 3 types of clients, Oracle, SQL Server, and SAP, the root folders on my Azure Storage will be oracle, sql_server, and sap followed by server/database/client names.

Additionally, it seems you may have to set up Azure IoT hub if you are going to ingest data from IoT devices.  If that is the case, this [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/route-iot-device-messages-to-azure-storage-with-azure-iot-hub/) would be helpful.

#### Staging Area

Will be an area for schema cleanup. I will have multiple ADF pipelines that transform polymorphic data from Landing Zone and ingest it into Staging Area. You will have to create schema (delta table) for each of your decomposed datasets and data sources. I recommend utilizing [Delta Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-intro) as it will be easy to manage and retrieve data.

The transformation options you will have are:

- Use only ADF transformation. It will allow you to [unnest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse) some nested XML columns as well as do some data cleansing and wrangling from Landing Zone so that the same dataset can be inserted into the same table.

  For your case, you may have to create particular ADF pipelines for each of datasets multiplied by client versions.
- Use an additional common ADF pipeline that ran Databricks transformation base on datasets and client versions. This will allow more complex transformations that ADF transformation is not capable of.

  For your case, there will also be a particular Databricks notebook for each of datasets multiplied by client versions.

As a result, different versions of one particular dataset will be extracted from raw files, cleaned up in terms of schema, and ingested into one table for **each data source**. There will be some duplicated data for master datasets across different data sources.

#### ODS Area

Will be an area for so-called single source of truth of your data. Multiple data sources will be merge into one.  Therefore, all duplicated data gets eliminated and relationships between dataset get clarified resulting in the second item per your question. If you have just one data source, this will also be an area for applying more data cleansing, such as, validation and consistency. As a result, one dataset will be stored in one table.

I recommend using ADF running Databricks, but for this time, we can use SQL notebook instead of Python because data is well inserted into the table in Staging area already.

The data at this stage can be consumed by Power BI.  Read [more](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-power-bi-integration-with-databricks-partner-connect/) about Power BI integration with Databricks.

Furthermore, if you still want a **data warehouse** or star schema for advance analytics, you can do further transformation (via again ADF and Databricks) and utilize [Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/overview-what-is).

#### Source Control

Fortunately, the tools that I mentioned above are already integrated with source code version control thanks to acquisition of Github by Microsoft. The Databricks notebook and ADF pipeline source codes can be versioning. Check [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, we have already stablished the ingestion pipeline and it is fairly similar to your suggestion. The main focus area is about how to process the data after ingestion to make it ready for BI reports, I have some question posted below with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your comprehensive answer PhuriChal! Indeed the data sources are always the same software, but with various different versions and unfortunately data properties are not always remain steady among those versions. Would it be an option to process the raw data after ingestion in order to unify and resolve unmatched properties using a high level programming language before processing them further in databricks?(We may have many of this processing code to refine the raw data for specific proposes)I have added an example in the original post.

```js
Version1:{
    'theProperty': 8
}
Version2:{
    'data':{
              'myProperty': 10
           }
}


Processing =>
Refined version: [{
    'property: 8
},
{
    'property: 10
}]
```

So that the inconsistencies are resolved before the data comes to databricks for further processing. Can this also be an option?

Comment: You're welcome! I have just realized this question is kind of schema evolution specific. Actually, Databricks notebook supports both Python and SQL, and I think Python is capable of doing your task. What you have to further develop additionally to my answer is something like Schema Registry. You may have to define Schema Enforcement and Evolution logic. Based on your example, there should be a control table that stores records like | version1 | property | theProperty | and | version2 | property | data.myProperty |. So that Spark can unnest and ingest data into correct field.

Comment: (Con't) If you have well defined versions of schemas, this will be easy to managed.  However, the more challenging is if you can receive new undefined versions from the client.  PySpark also supports an operation such as mergeSchema as well, so you can even ingest unknown schemas into your Staging table.  This is what I found a useful [overview](https://databricks.com/discover/diving-into-delta-lake-talks/schema-enforcement-evolution) of implementing schema enforcing and evolution on Databricks.